# gnuplot nonsense plotting error

Tags: gnuplot

Imagine I have a simple data file called 'test_gnu.txt' as follow:

```
0.32,0.116,0.398989898989899 
0.34,0.010,0.01212121212121212 
0.36,0.035,0.11313131313131312 
0.38,0.022,0.06666666666666665 
0.4,0.070,0.11919191919191922 
0.42,0.026,0.06565656565656566 
0.44,0.077,0.15858585858585858 
0.46,0.011,0.01616161616161616
```

I want to plot first digit versus 2nd digit. Therefore the command will be:

plot 'test_gnu.txt' using 1:2 t 'lablablab'

It gives me stupid errors and the result is nothing to do with the data. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
set datafile separator ","
```

before you can plot.

http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.0/gnuplot.html#set_datafile_separator

Comment: Thanks. My problem is gnuplot tutorials are normally too boring to read carefully!